# How can I allow only Y/N to be input in Read-Host without having to press Enter in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to have something like a `Read-Host` to ask the user if they want to output to the file listed or not. With this I want them to either press `y` or `n` and then the code continues rather than then pressing y/n then pressing enter as well. At the moment this all works well but again it's not quite what I'm wanting.

I've tried looking into `Readkey` and `SendKeys` (to push Enter for the user) but neither work as they seem to only execute after the user has pushed Enter on the `Read-Host`. I'm still very new to Powershell so I'm not entirely sure whether it's actually possible or not and I've spent too much time googling/testing to find an answer that works. If I was to use `Write-Host` or something to do this, it needs to not show up in the log.

I've included the necessary part of my script below. It basically asks the user if the file location is correct. If it is they press `y` and it uses it for the output, otherwise if they push `n` then it loads the `FolderBrowserDialog` for them to select the folder they want.

I should also note this is all within a `Tee-object` as this code is what determines where the Tee-object output goes to.

```
$OutputYN = Read-Host "Do you want the output file generated to $startDirectory\FolderList.txt? (Y/N)"
If (“y”,”n” -notcontains $OutputYN) {
    Do {
    $OutputYN = Read-Host "Please input either a 'Y' for yes or a 'N' for no"
    } While (“y”,”n” -notcontains $OutputYN)
}
if ($OutputYN -eq "Y") { 
        $OutputLoc = $startDirectory
}
elseif ($OutputYN -eq "N") {
    $OutputLocDir = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $OutputLocDir.Description = "Select a folder for the output"
    $OutputLocDir.SelectedPath = "$StartDirectory"
    if ($OutputLocDir.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") {
        $OutputLoc = $OutputLocDir.SelectedPath
        $OutputLoc = $OutputLoc.TrimEnd('\')
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I should have been a little more clear. I had already tried message box type stuff as well but I'd really prefer if there is a way that the user types in a y or a n. I'm not really interested in a popup box that the user has to click. If it's not possible then so be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Readkey is the right way.

Use the following as template.

```
:prompt while ($true) {
    switch ([console]::ReadKey($true).Key) {
        { $_ -eq [System.ConsoleKey]::Y } { break prompt }
        { $_ -eq [System.ConsoleKey]::N } { return }
        default { Write-Error "Only 'Y' or 'N' allowed!" }
    }
}
write-host 'do it' -ForegroundColor Green
```

`:prompt` gives the outer loop (while) a name which can be used in the switch statement to directly break out entirely via `break prompt` (and not within the switch statement).

Alternative (for Windows):
Use a MessageBox.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$messageBoxResult = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Do you want the output file generated to $startDirectory\FolderList.txt?" , 'Question' , [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo , [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Question)
switch ($messageBoxResult) {
    { $_ -eq [System.Windows.MessageBoxResult]::Yes } {
        'do this'
        break
    }

    { $_ -eq [System.Windows.MessageBoxResult]::No } { 
        'do that'
        break 
    }

    default { 
        # stop
        return # or EXIT
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance I'm not sure how to incorporate this to my code to work?

Comment: Place your code for "Y" into the switch statement condition for "Y" right before the "break prompt" ```{ $OutputLoc = $startDirectory <new line> break prompt }``` then place the code for "N" also accordingly, but replace the "return" with "break prompt" (like for "Y")

Comment: I meant more of where do I put the question and where does the `:prompt` go in relation? I can't find anything googling that uses `:prompt`.

Comment: Ah sorry. Put the question on top before my code. ```:prompt``` is like a GoTo statement in batch. You can find more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-5.1#using-a-labeled-break-in-a-loop

Comment: And don't use "Read-Host" for your question. Use "Write-Host" instead

Comment: Ok I got it to work and does what I want. However, the issue I feared is the question (and looped error responses/questions now show up in my `Tee-Object` log which I can't have. This is why I used `Read-Host` as it doesn't show up in the log. Is there another way other than `Write-Host` that will show only in the console and not the log? `Write-Error` seems to show everything and goes to the log so I don't want that either. I will be back in 8-10 hours from now.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution to my answer (MessageBox).

Comment: I guess that's the only other way is it? I forgot to mention I had already tried a message box (not this type though which certainly looks better) so I may possibly use it if it's the only option. I'd just prefer it all stay in the console. Great learning opportunity as well.
Otherwise is there some easy way to maybe pause `Tee-object` or skip certain lines from logging etc? If it's too much then not to worry I will ponder on.

Comment: Never mind I've changed how I did that bit because it wasn't working anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You can hide the user input by using an overload of ```ReadKey()``` -> ```ReadKey($true)```. And concerning the question output .. I've never used Tee-Object before. Does Tee-Object really redirects ```Write-Host ...```-statements as well? Thought it can only redirect the Standard Output Stream.

Comment: It didn't matter in the end because I was trying to allow the user to choose the output of the log within the `tee-object` which seems you cannot do as you need the log location from the `& {` that starts the log so I've now put the choice at the start of the script. Not as ideal but works great. (Plus lets me colour the text). But yes the `Write-Host` was showing up in the log when I had it inside the part of the code that was logging.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Get-logicalYesNo([string]$question) {
do { $sAnswer = Read-Host "$question [Y/N]" } until ($sAnswer.ToUpper()[0] -match '[yYnN]')
    return ($sAnswer.ToUpper()[0] -match '[Y]') #return  $True or $False
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible in the console. But when I need the user to write one answer of a specified set, I use a do-until-loop like:

```
Do {
    $a = Read-Host "Y / N"
} until ( 'y', 'n' - contains $a )
```

Comment: Thanks but if you see that's what I already have in my code except mine is `While` and yours is `Until`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$title    = 'Question'
$question = 'Do you want the output file generated to $startDirectory\FolderList.txt?'

$choices = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]
$choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&Yes'))
$choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&No'))

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
if ($decision -eq 0) {
    Write-Host 'Yes'
} else {
    Write-Host 'No'
}
```

Comment: Hi I forgot to add to my OP about already trying this sort of thing (I've updated it now). It's not what I'm wanting but thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can do it :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

$result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do you want the output file generated to $startDirectory\FolderList.txt?' , "Question" , [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Question)
if ($result -eq 'Yes') {
    "Yes"
}
else
{
    "No"

}
```